# IR spectra and melting point range comparison

Tags: organic-chemistry

I did a Diels-Alder experiment in lab, and the desired product was 9,10-dihydroanthracene-9,10-α,β-succinic anhydride. According to my IR spectra, I believe I isolated the product. However, my observed melting point range is 269-272°C, while the literature melting point is 262-264°C.

How significant is my melting point discrepancy? 
And am I overlooking peaks in my IR that would be indicative of an impurity in my sample?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! For an impure sample, I'd rather expect a melting point depression. Did you heat up too fast and miss the start of the melting process? I'd check and calibrate the melting point apparatus with some reference samples.

Comment: Personally I don't think the IR spectrum is of much use in finding impurities.

Comment: Thank you @KlausWarzecha! Unfortunately, as a student I do not have access to the laboratory to check the apparatus. In general, how can I tell how significant my discrepancy in ranges is? In my case it is only a few degrees, but a few degrees seems significant to me.

Comment: Impurities only *lower* melting points, they never raise melting points. I agree that the most common causes of an elevated melting point are 1. increasing temperature too quickly then 2. an improperly calibrated thermometer.

Comment: You are right, a few degrees are significant. Too bad that you don't have further access to the melting point apparatus. Even measuring the melting points of your starting materials, anthracene and maleic anhydride, would give some hints on  how much the apparatus is off  - or whether you botched the measurement ;-)

Comment: Indeed! :)  Thank you so much @KlausWarzecha!

Comment: Calibrating the thermometer is certainly the right idea but reagent grade anthracene is only 97% pure. I'd want something purer to calibrate the thermometer. It would nice to bracket the desired MP of 260 C also. http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/a89200?lang=en&region=US